# Find specific div in forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm wondering how to select a child when the callback of a forEach does not directly refer to the desired element.

```
const $searchField = document.querySelectorAll('.js-search');

if ($searchField.length > 0) {
  $searchField.forEach(function($el) {
    // $el = .js-search
    $el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      $el.classList.add('is-active');
    });

    // Here, i need to target the input, not .js-search
    $el.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      if ($el.value.length > 0) {
         $el.classList.add('is-active');
       } else {
         $el.classList.remove('is-active')
       }
    //});
  });
}
```

Here, `$el` refers to the parent `.js-search` so obviously the keyup can not work. I would like to make sure to select the input, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Demo is available on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lorraineS/pen/wbgwPZ)!

The goal is to keep the state is-active when the search is completed (has at least 1 character).

Thanks

Comment: `$el.children` or `$el.querySelector`?

Answer (score 3):

Just select the child `input`'s `.value`, instead of the `$el`'s `.value`:

```
const $searchField = document.querySelectorAll('.js-search');
$searchField.forEach(function($el) {
  // $el = .js-search
  $el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $el.classList.add('is-active');
  });

  const input = $el.querySelector('input');
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (input.value.length > 0) {
       $el.classList.add('is-active');
     } else {
       $el.classList.remove('is-active')
     }
  });
});
```

Note that there's no need for the `if` check if you don't want - calling `forEach` on an empty collection won't throw an error, it just won't iterate over anything.

You also might consider including a polyfill for `NodeList.prototype.forEach` (if you aren't already), since older browsers don't support it. (Alternatively, transform the collection into an array, or use `Array.prototype.forEach.call`)

A bit opinion-based, but there's no need to prefix variable names with `$` - this isn't PHP. Often, a `$` prefix is done when indicating that something is a jQuery (`$`) collection. If you're doing DOM manipulation, probably best not to use a variable name that starts with `$`, to avoid confusion for future readers of your code.

Comment: I didn't know that we can select an element as simply with querySelector in a forEach ... Thanks.
About the prefix, it's just to tell me it's an DOM element. It's more of a personal convention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.querySelector('input');` where `this` will the parent element and `querySelector` will get the first `input` child element

```js
const $searchField = document.querySelectorAll('.js-search');

if ($searchField.length > 0) {
  $searchField.forEach(function($el) {
    $el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      $el.classList.add('is-active');
      let $input = this.querySelector('input');
      $input.addEventListener('keyup', function(et) {
        console.log(et.target.value)
      });

    });

  });


  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.js-search').length) {
      closeSearchs();
    }

    $('.js-search.is-active').not($(event.target).closest('.js-search')).removeClass('is-active');
  });
}

function closeSearchs() {
  $searchField.forEach(function($el) {
    $el.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
}
```

```css
.field-search {
  position: relative;
  &.is-active {
    .search-input {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
      color: white;
    }
  }
  .search-input {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 4.5rem;
    transition: background-color .2s;
    width: 365px;
    &::placeholder {
      color: black;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    &.is-active {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="field-search js-search">
  <input type="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```